# Plotting the solution to the heat equation in polar corrdinates

Tags: plotting

I have code for solving the heat equation in polar coordinates.  NDSolveValue gives a very clean result (with a mild warning.) I have plotted the solution with Revolution3D and with Plot3D, but I am not satisfied. Is there a better way to plot this or are these acceptable visualizations? (I have only shown one graph from each at t = 20).

```
Table[RevolutionPlot3D[
s[r, \[Theta], t], {r, -2, 2}, {\[Theta], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
AxesLabel -> {r, \[Theta], T[r, \[Theta], t]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 70}}, 
AspectRatio -> 1], {t, 0, 80, 20}]
```

[image]

```
Table[Plot3D[
s[r, \[Theta], t], {r, -2, 2}, {\[Theta], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
AxesLabel -> {r, \[Theta], T[r, \[Theta], t]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {-5, 70}}], {t, 0,80, 
20}]
```

[image]

Here is the code that generated these solutions along with a CountourPlot:

```
Clear[s]
a = 1;
s = NDSolveValue[{D[u[r, theta, t], t] == 
a^2 D[u[r, theta, t], {r, 2}] + (a^2/r) D[u[r, theta, t], 
   r] + (a^2/r^2) D[u[r, theta, t], {theta, 2}], 
DirichletCondition[u[r, theta, t] == 0, True], 
u[r, theta, 0] == 250}, 
u, {r, -2, 2}, {theta, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 300}]

Table[ContourPlot[
s1[r, \[Theta], t], {r, -2, 2}, {\[Theta], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, 2, 300, 50}]
```

I think there is a problem with the solution as r -> 0.

[image]

Comment: A better way in what sense? What aspect would you like to see refined/updated? Also, it would be better to also provide the code that generates the solutions to these equations. If for your own reasons you don't want to share the PDE solver you have, perhaps you can give us a MWE -a test function so we can try and plot and help!

Comment: I am happy to provide the code for the solution below. I am wondering if there is a convention for showing the result or if there is a clearly superior way to visualize the result.

Comment: I just added the code for the solutions.

Comment: the code you posted is wrong. Try copying it to new worksheet with clean kernel and run. You will see the errors.

Comment: It was missing the numerical value for and there was a typo. It works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have radius $r$ from `-2 to +2` in polar coordinates. $r$ is the length of the `r` coordinates which must be positive. In addition, the angle needs to be from either `0` to `2 Pi` or `-Pi` to `Pi`.  That is enpugh.

Another option to display the result is to use `ParametricPlot3D`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 1;
lengthOfRadius = 2;
pde = D[u[r, theta, t], t] == a^2*Laplacian[u[r, theta, t], {r, theta}, "Polar"]
ic = u[r, theta, 0] == 10;
s = NDSolveValue[{pde, DirichletCondition[u[r, theta, t] == 0, True], 
   ic}, u, {r, 0, lengthOfRadius}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

And now to display the solution after 1 second

```
time=1;
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], s[r, theta, time]}, {r, 0, 
  lengthOfRadius}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And at time=5 seconds all the heat seem to have been dissipated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using your `RevolutionPlot3D` it now shows as after one second

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 s[r, theta, 1], {r, 0, lengthOfRadius}, {theta, -Pi, Pi}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) a great answer as always. Maybe you can, also, mention that there was a potentially harmful extrapolation before. The PDE was solved until $t=100$ and then there in the `Table` $t$ went all the way to $300$.

Comment: Thank you - very helpful!